# Facebook and Instagram, get and display own post on own website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

This has been an immense source of frustration for me for a few weeks now.

The core of this question is how do i get and display my own posts from Instagram and Facebook without having to implement some form of end user authentication process?

I have a client that has a requirement to display their latest posts in their own styling which means embedded is not an option.

I see now, my only option is to use the graph API which in itself is not an issue. What I do have an issue with is all the loops we have to jump through to simply display our own posts. I cannot seem to use the AppID/Secret to get to a page post without the **'Page Public Content Access' feature.**

If i use the graph API i have to authenticate to get the page access token and when I use that to try to get the posts i get the above response about public page access.

To get that I have to then prepare my app for review where I have to show a screencast of the end user login mechanism, of which there is none or any requirement for one...

As the admin/owner of the page surely that is enough to display posts from it rather than going through this app review mess?

Has anybody else been through this hell themselves in the last few weeks? This has left me feeling somewhat incompetent by failing to complete what used to be a very simple task.

I seem to be able to get to the Instagram posts easy enough after acquiring the page access token.

the only really relevant material I have found discussing this is here..

[Get instagram own/self feed with facebook graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365510/get-instagram-own-self-feed-with-facebook-graph-api)
And here
[Is there CURRENTLY anyway to fetch Instagram user media without authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852080/is-there-currently-anyway-to-fetch-instagram-user-media-without-authentication)

Looking through that, it doesn't look like its very feasible anymore.

I am eager to hear about other experiences here.

**Edit:**
I guess the main question here is how do i get past the **'Page Public Content Access' feature** response for getting a page post.

**Edit 2.0:**
Another thing, I am interested in is what the intended workflow look likes like now. Am i going to be forced in to creating a back office flow just to re-authenticate and get new page access tokens when they expire? Is there now no way of keeping this automated and without human interaction?

Comment: are you sure you are trying this with a page token of the page in question, and not just ANY page token? if you want to get data from a specific page, you have to use a page token of that specific page.

Comment: _“Is there now no way of keeping this automated and without human interaction?”_ - no, because that is rather the point of the changes they made in light of the recent “scandals”. Apps that might get forgotten about at some point are not supposed to be able to still grab data for all eternity.

Comment: _“I guess the main question here is how do i get past the 'Page Public Content Access' feature response for getting a page post.”_ - you don’t, because for an app with this stated purpose they won’t approve that feature in the first place; You want to use a proper page access token, then this isn’t PPCA any more in the first place.